# Why is JSON.session getting a Value of 0?

Tags: javascript, php, json, session

Why is JSON.session returning a value of 0?

i was trying to detect if a session existed in the server, yet afeter messing arounf in the code, i found that even if the variable $_SESSION has data, java recieves a false value.

js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    const JSON = await dataFetch(USER_API, 'getUser');

    if (JSON.session) {

        if (JSON.status) {
            console.log('hello');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('bye');
    }
});
```

session is being started in the server and it has values applied to it but it still returns a value of 0 when checking if it has values.

dataFetch

```
    async function dataFetch(filename, action, form = null) {
de la petición.
    const OPTIONS = {};
    // Se determina el tipo de petición a realizar.
    if (form) {
        OPTIONS.method = 'post';
        OPTIONS.body = form;
    } else {
        OPTIONS.method = 'get';
    }
    try {
del servidor.
        const PATH = new URL(SERVER_URL + filename);
solicitada.
        PATH.searchParams.append('action', action);
petición.
        const RESPONSE = await fetch(PATH.href, OPTIONS);
        // Se retorna el resultado en formato JSON.
        return RESPONSE.json();
    } catch (error) {
ocurre un problema.
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

server

```
<?php
require_once('../entities/dto/armero.php');

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    
    session_start();

    $armero = new Armero;

    $result = array('status' => 0, 'session' => 0, 'message' => null, 'exception' => null, 'dataset' => null, 'username' => null);

    if (isset($_SESSION['id_armero'])) {
        switch (isset($_GET['action'])) {
            case 'getUser':
                if (isset($_SESSION['correo_armero'])) {
                    $result['status'] = 1;
                    $result['username'] = $_SESSION['correo_armero'];
                } else {
                    $result['exception'] = 'Alias de usuario indefinido';
                }
                break;
            case 'logOut':
                if (session_destroy()) {
                    $result['status'] = 1;
                    $result['message'] = 'Sesion eliminada correctamente';
                } else {
                    $result['exception'] = 'Ocurrio un problema al cerrar la sesion';
                }
                break;
            
            default:
                $result['exception'] = 'Acción no disponible dentro de la sesión';
        }
    } else {
        switch ($_GET['action']) {
            case 'readUsers':
                if ($armero->readAll()) {
                    $result['status'] = 1;
                    $result['message'] = 'Debe autenticarse para ingresar';
                } else {
                    $result['exception'] = 'debe crear un usuario para comenzar';
                }
                break;
            case 'signUp':
                $_POST = Validator::validateForm($_POST);
                if (!$armero->setNombre($_POST['nombre'])) {
                    $result['exception'] = 'Nombres incorrectos';
                } elseif (!$armero->setApellido($_POST['apellido'])) {
                    $result['exception'] = 'Apellidos incorrectos';
                } elseif (!$armero->setCorreo($_POST['email'])) {
                    $result['exception'] = 'Correo incorrecto';
                } elseif (!$armero->setTelefono($_POST['telefono'])) {
                    $result['exception'] = 'Alias incorrecto';
                } elseif ($_POST['codigo_ser'] != $_POST['confirmar']) {
                    $result['exception'] = 'Claves diferentes';
                } elseif (!$armero->setCodigo($_POST['codigo_ser'])) {
                    $result['exception'] = Validator::getPasswordError();
                } elseif ($armero->createRow()) {
                    $result['status'] = 1;
                    $result['message'] = 'Usuario registrado correctamente';
                } else {
                    $result['exception'] = Database::getException();
                }
                break;
            case 'logIn':
                $_POST = Validator::validateForm($_POST);
                if (!$armero->checkUser($_POST['email'])) {
                    $result['exception'] = 'Alias Incorrecto';
                } elseif ($armero->checkPassword($_POST['clave']) && $armero->checkState()) {
                    $result['status'] = 1;
                    $result['message'] = 'Autenticacion Correcta';
                    $_SESSION['id_armero'] = $armero->getId();
                    $_SESSION['correo_armero'] = $armero->getCorreo();
                } else {
                    $result['exception'] = 'Clave incorrecta o usuario no activo';
                }
                break;
            default:
                $result['exception'] = 'Acción no disponible fuera de la sesión';    
        }
    }
    header('content-type: aplication/json; charset=utf-8');
    print(json_encode($result));
} else {
    print(json_encode('Recurso no disponible'));
}
```

Comment: You need to show the server code.

Comment: And the code for `dataFetch()`.

Comment: Don't use `JSON` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in `JSON` object.

Comment: @Barmar i just added the code for dataFetch() and the server

Comment: You never do `result['session'] = 1;` in the server.

Comment: Change `'session' => 0` to `'session' => 1`

Comment: @Barmar thanks, i dont know how i didnt noticed

Answer (score 1):

as pointed out, i forgot to add 'result['session'] = 1;' in the server, i thank the ones that pointed out this very crucial detail i forgot to add

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).